# Ошибка при записи изображения cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'

Tags: python, opencv

```
    import cv2
    import os
    from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
    detector = MTCNN()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
    for i in range(2000):
        __, frame = cap.read()
        result = detector.detect_faces(frame)
        if result != []:
            for person in result:
            bounding_box = person['box']
            keypoints = person['keypoints']
                frame = frame[bounding_box[1]:bounding_box[1] + bounding_box[3], 
                              bounding_box[0]:bounding_box[0] + bounding_box[2]]
                if not frame is None:
                    cv2.imwrite("Path" + str(i) + ".jpg", frame) # - здесь ошибка при записи 
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

Ошибка вроде бы связана с тем что cv2 получает пустое изображение, но как он умудряется его получить, я не знаю.
Что делать?
```

Comment: А откуда берётся массив `bounding_box`? Его получения нет в коде

Comment: Я лишние удалил случайно. (уже поправил)